# Updating date field based on two other timestamp fields

Tags: mysql, sql, date, sql-update

Hy folk, i have below sample table structure,

```sql
mysql> SELECT * FROM tbl_test_timestamp;
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | t1                  | t2                  | date_created        | date_updated        |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 16 | 2019-01-22 12:47:05 | 2019-03-15 14:50:13 | 2019-01-22 12:47:05 | 2020-05-14 16:11:22 |
| 20 | 2019-01-24 09:35:19 | 2019-03-14 07:12:31 | 2019-01-24 09:35:19 | 2020-05-14 16:11:22 |
| 22 | 2019-01-24 16:46:20 | 2019-01-24 16:46:20 | 2019-01-24 16:45:35 | 2020-05-14 16:11:22 |
| 23 | 2019-01-25 14:03:33 | 2019-04-08 07:48:53 | 2019-01-25 13:55:42 | 2020-05-14 16:11:22 |
+----+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

I need to set the date_updated field to t1 or t2 whichever is greater. I need to run this query in more than 7 millions of record.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `greatest()`:

```
update tbl_test_timestamp set date_updated = greatest(t1, t2)
```

Beware that `greatest()` returns `null` if any of its arguments is `null`. Depending on your data and your use case, this might, or might not be something to worry about.

Answer (score 1):

It will take a long time, but you can do:

```
update t
    set date_updated = greatest(t1, t2);
```

Updating all rows may take a long time.  You might consider a view instead.